# creating pandas-vectorized 'subtraction' table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series with a DatetimeIndex and an integer value.  I want to make a table that shows the change in value from each time to all the other subsequent times.

Below is a visual representation of what I want.  The gray and orange cells are irrelevant data.

[image]
I can't figure out a way to create this in a vectorized style inside pandas.

```
z = pd.DatetimeIndex(periods=10, freq='H', start='2018-12-1')
import random
df = pd.DataFrame(random.sample(range(1, 100), 10), index=z, columns=['foo'])
```

I've tried things like:

```
df['foo'].sub(df['foo'].transpose())
```

But that doesn't work.

The output DataFrame could either have a multindex (beforeTime, AfterTime)  or could be a single index "beforeTime" and then have  a column for each possible "aftertime".  I think they're equivalent, as I can use the unstack() and related functions to get the shape I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `np.substract` with `np.outer` to calculate all the values and create the dataframe like:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame(np.subtract.outer(df.foo, df.foo), 
                         columns= df.index.time, index=df.index.time)
print (df_output.head())
          00:00:00  01:00:00  02:00:00  03:00:00  04:00:00  05:00:00  \
00:00:00         0         6        -7       -57       -33         3   
01:00:00        -6         0       -13       -63       -39        -3   
02:00:00         7        13         0       -50       -26        10   
03:00:00        57        63        50         0        24        60   
04:00:00        33        39        26       -24         0        36   

          06:00:00  07:00:00  08:00:00  09:00:00  
00:00:00       -53       -28         5        17  
01:00:00       -59       -34        -1        11  
02:00:00       -46       -21        12        24  
03:00:00         4        29        62        74  
04:00:00       -20         5        38        50
```

You can use `np.triu` to set to `0` all the values in grey in your example such as:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.triu(np.subtract.outer(df.foo, df.foo)), columns = ...)
```

Note the `.time` is not necessary when creating the `columns=` and `index=`, it was to copy and paste a dataframe readable